# Cleaning unicode characters while writing to csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, unicode, python-unicode

I am using a certain REST api to get data, and then attemping to write it to a csv using python 2.7

In the csv, every item with a tuple has u' ' around it. For example, with the 'tags' field i am retrieving, i am getting [u'01d/02d/major/--', u'45m/04h/12h/24h', u'internal', u'net', u'premium_custom', u'priority_fields_swapped', u'priority_saved', u'problem', u'urgent', u'urgent_priority_issue'] . However, if I print the data in the program prior to it being written in the csv, the data looks fine, .ie ('01d/02d/major--', '45m/04h/12h/24h', etc). So I am assuming I have to modify something in the csv write command or within the the csv writer object itself. My question is how to write the data into the csv properly so that there are no unicode characters.

Comment: The `u'...'` around the text elements show that you are dealing with unicode strings. Why would you want to avoid that? If you don't (want to) understand Python 2's data model, why don't you switch to Python 3?

Answer (score 0):

In Python3:
Just define the encoding when opening the csv file to write in.

If the row contains non ascii chars, you will get `UnicodeEncodeError`

```
row = [u'01d/02d/major/--', u'45m/04h/12h/24h', u'internal', u'net', u'premium_custom', u'priority_fields_swapped', u'priority_saved', u'problem', u'urgent', u'urgent_priority_issue']
import csv
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='ascii') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: any alternative for python 2.7?